# Get full path to nested list

Tags: c#, recursion, nested

I need to make a method that finds by the ID of an entity in a nested list, the path from the root node.

```
public class Application
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public List<Component> Components { get; set; }
}

public class Component
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path
    public List<Component> Components { get; set; }
}
```

For example:

```
-Name: Windows: 
-Path: "D:\Windows"
-components:
[0] Path: "Microsoft.net"
    Name: ".netfolder"
    Components: 
    [0] Path: "Framework"
        Name: ".netfolder"
        Components: 
        [0] Path: "v3.0"
            Name: "3.0folder"
            Components: 
    [1] Path: "Microsoft.net"
        Name: "Framework64"
        Components:
```

If I called the method with "3.0folder" as parameter, it should return the nodes Path of each node:

```
{ "D:\Windows", "Microsoft.net", "Framework", "v3.0" }
```

Comment: Are the components again recursive as in [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318372/linq-nested-list-contains)? You should at least provide  the initialization of your list with meaningful sample data. That would help us to help you.

Comment: Tim you are completely right. I am working on a recursive model to explain how stuff is organized somewhere. I will improve the example for you to have a better idea.

Comment: There, I improved the model, example, everything. Thanks Tim.

Answer (score 0):

Your current design makes it a bit tricky, I would introduce a parent to your `Component` class, this would allow you to traverse up the hierarchy and build the path up. That means all you need to worry about is finding the component.

You could also do the same for the search, only this time traverse down the hierarchy e.g.

```
public class Component
{
    public Component Parent { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Component> Components { get; set; }
    public Component FindByName(string searchTerm)
    {
        if (searchTerm == Name)
            return this;

        var result = null;
        foreach (var c in Components)
        {
            var result = c.FindByName(searchTerm);
            if (result != null) 
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public string FullPath
    {
        get { return this.GetFullPath(); }   
    }

    private string GetFullPath()
    {
        var fullPath = Path;
        var parent = Parent;
        while (parent != null)
        {
            fullPath = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", parent.FullPath, System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, fullPath)
        }
        return path;
    }
}
```

Code isn't tested, but you get the idea. Each component has the information it needs to either traverse up/down the tree.

Also, you should make `Application` derive from `Component` so it can inherit all the same properties/behaviour without duplicating the code.